# Convert Timespan to IADSLargeInteger for Active Directory Setting

Tags: c#, active-directory, password-policy

I want to set MaxPasswordAge Property of a DirectoryEntry object. I believe it is of type IADSLargeInteger. Now i want to set it to some value programatically. How do i convert a timespan to IADSLargeInteger. Eg. If i want to set it as 10 days how do i do it. Setting it Directly doesnt work.

```
DirectoryEntry child = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
child.Properties["minPwdAge"].Value = ...
```

How do i set that value to n days? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can actually write to this property. In any case, you want to get this in FileTime format which a DateTime object will give you as a property off of it.

Comment: i am able to write to this property using a hard coded int64 equivalent of 0 days, convert it to iadsLargeInteger object and assigned it to that property. That gets  reflected in Password Policy too. I wanted to know a generalized way of doing it.